# print curl request

Tags: c++, libcurl

To see what's wrong I need to print request made by curl. How can I do that? Please do not advise doing

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
```

I'm posting multipart message and it does not print the whole request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html) is your friend.

See these examples: [debug.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/debug.html) and [multi-debugcallback.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-debugcallback.html)